# Is it possible to run code after each line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I understand that it is possible to decorate methods with before and after hooks in ruby, but is it possible to do it for each line of a given method?

For example, I have an automation test and I want to verify that after each step there no error shown on the page. The error is shown as a red div and is not visible to Ruby as `raise` or anything like that, so I have to check for it manually (there are several other use cases as well).

I understand that it might be possible using `set_trace_func`. But I think this may bring more problems than benefits since it works over entire call tree (and requires me to filter it myself).

**UPDATE (clarification)**:

I am interested in intercepting all actions (or calls) that are performed *within* a given method. This means unspecified number of classes is called, so I can't just intercept any given set of classes/methods.

Answer (score 2):

It is, and you can get a full description of how to do it in section 8.9 of [The Ruby Programming Language](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516178/). Running the code on each invocation of the method involves sending the method to a `TracedObject` class that has an implementation for `method_missing`. Whenever it receives a message, it invokes `method_missing` and executes whatever code you have assigned to it. (This is, of course, for general tracing).

That's the general description of the procedure for doing it, you can consult the book for details.

Comment: My understanding is that TracedObject (http://books.google.ru/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA286 ?) can intercept all calls to a methods of given class, however what if I want to intercept all calls from a specific method? The method in question may call more than one class, so it essentially requires me to wrap all called classes in TracedObjects (which seems kind of impossible as general solution)?

Comment: If you're interested in a single method, you merely filter for that inside of `method_missing`;  but you did state that you don't like the idea of filtering. You're right that this would be an inelegant to difficult solution for a method that messages on several classes.

Perhaps you should edit the question to add that second requirement (about several classes).

Comment: I am interested in outgoing calls from single method, not the ingoing calls to it. Or I want to intercept each line of the original method, as described in the original question.

Comment: Ha, you're going to kill me, but I think what you are looking for is to be found in 8.11.3. of "The Ruby Programming Language", but you're still left with the problem of having to set up the tracing in each class where the methods are being used.

At the very least, you could use this as a starting point towards a solution --- it would give you line-by-line tracing.

Comment: This is cool and I now know what the eigenclass is. But it still requires me to call trace! on each instance used within the method. After some consideration I think I'll go with set_trace_func -- I'll post a sample as a reply when I'm done with it.

Comment: The `tap` method from Ruby 1.9 might also be something that would work as well:

http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2008-10-29/kestrel.markdown

http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&lpg=PP1&dq=ruby%20programming%20language&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q=tap&f=false

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want tracing on *every* method call on *every* object, but only during the span of every call to *one* *particular* method. In that case, you could just redefine the method to turn on- and off instrumentation.  First, use the universal instrumentation suggsted in [Pinochle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199179/is-it-possible-to-run-code-after-each-line-in-ruby/1199640#1199640), then redefine the method in question as follows:

```
# original definition, in /lib/foo.rb:
class Foo
  def bar(baz)
    do_stuff
  end
end

# redefinition, in /test/add_instrumentation_to_foo.rb:
Foo.class_eval do
  original_bar = instance_method(:bar)
  def bar(baz)
    TracedObject.install!
    original_bar.bind(self).call(baz)
    TracedObject.uninstall!
  end
end
```

You'd need to write the `install!` and `uninstall` methods, but they should be pretty trivial: just set or unset a class variable and check for it in the instrumentation logic.

Comment: If I read 8.11.3 correctly, then there should not be a global TracedObject.install! available, since it's not a self.install!, it is available only on instance level.

Answer (score 0):

What about (just tries)

```
    class User

      def initialize(name)
        @name = name
      end

      def say_hello
        puts "hello #{@name}"
      end

      def say_hi(friend)
        puts "hi #{@name} from #{friend}"
      end

      def say_bye(a, b = 'Anna')
        puts "bye #{a} and #{b}"
      end

    end

    User.class_eval do
      User.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
        original = instance_method(method)
        define_method method do |*options| 
          parameters = original.parameters
          if parameters.empty?
            original.bind(self).call
          else
            original.bind(self).call(*options)
          end
          puts __method__
        end
      end
    end

    user = User.new("John")

    user.say_hello
    user.say_hi("Bob")
    user.say_bye("Bob")
    user.say_bye("Bob", "Lisa")
```

outputs:

```
    hello John
    say_hello
    hi John from Bob
    say_hi
    bye Bob and Anna
    say_bye
    bye Bob and Lisa
    say_bye
```