# Is it possible to run a PHP function after each line of a PHP script is executed?

Tags: php, apache

My question is similar to this: [Is it possible to run code after each line in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199179/is-it-possible-to-run-code-after-each-line-in-ruby)
However I want to do it in PHP.

Is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: Having the need to execute a function after each line sounds somewhat odd to me. Can you explain why you would need that?

Comment: Present us with the actual root problem and we can advise, rather than your own stab at a solution :)

Comment: There is no problem, only interest. (Wasn't logged in when I posted this question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) a [tick handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks):

> **Ticks**
>
> A tick is an event that occurs for every N low-level tickable statements executed by the parser within the declare block. The value for N is specified using ticks=N within the declare blocks's directive section.
>
> Not all statements are tickable. Typically, condition expressions and argument expressions are not tickable.

As you can see, it's not exactly as "each line of code" unless you only write one tickable statement each line. But it's the closest you can get.

#### Example:

```
declare(ticks=1);
register_tick_function(function() {
    echo "tick_handler() called\n";
});

echo 'Line 1', PHP_EOL;
echo 'Line 2', PHP_EOL;
echo strtoupper('Line 3'), PHP_EOL;
```

will output ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/j4vQ1Q)):

```
tick_handler() called
Line 1
tick_handler() called
Line 2
tick_handler() called
LINE 3
tick_handler() called
```

Comment: +1. well done. you beat me to it, while I was spending ages trying to dig up that manual page.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is within PHP. You could, however, write a PHP script that took your original script and inserted an extra line after each line of the original.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting a wrapper around your original PHP, like so:

```
<?PHP
$lines = file('original.php');

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    eval($line);
    your_function();
}
?>
```