# Add more code to the end of function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Is there anyway to insert more code to the end of several function in Ruby?

Here I have some method

```
def foo
  # do something
end

def bar
  # do something else
end
```

Now I want to puts a code line like `p "#{__method__}"` to the end of each function `foo` and `bar`. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: What about a wrapper function with a function pointer as a parameter?

Comment: Please see this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199179/is-it-possible-to-run-code-after-each-line-in-ruby/20661999#20661999 just tried it but posted in different thread. interesting task

Comment: @ Igor: Thank you for useful link. I didn't find out the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can not be done, but something similar you can do dynamically using meta-programming. [`Method#name`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-name) will give you the same result, what you will bet getting when you would call [`__method__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__). Here is a code to show you the logic, I am thinking right now :

```
def foo
  x = 2
end

def bar
  y = 3
end

[:foo,:bar].each do |m|
   method(m).instance_eval{ val = call; puts "#{name} returned #{val * 2} after multiply by 2"}
end
```

**output**

```
foo returned 4 after multiply by 2
bar returned 6 after multiply by 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your urgent reply. Actually I want to do addition process at the end of each function, but must have the `__method__`. BTW, your comment can help me, I will try to do with this way.

Comment: How can I add those logic code to `foo` and `bar` function, and those code will be called only when I call `foo`? Your idea is great, but when I call `foo`, the return still is `2`.

Comment: @PhươngJLêH Try it the way I coded... I don't know about the actual code you are having.. What I shown you, the *tip*.. :)